# access help to dynamicaly determin a records date changes across fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a MS access database with a table such as the one below and i am trying to figure out the sql needed to determine the total number of times the date changes across all the fields for each defectID record.

also, note that each day i add a field to the table, so if this can be made dynamic that would be best.

when there are no dates i would like the result to display 0 (zero)

[image]

thanks all

Comment: Adding a new field to your table every day is a pretty terrible way to design it.  Would normalizing not work best for that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you definitely have a normalization issue here.

you should consider moving the date to another table - maybe similar to the following:

```
Retest Estimate
-----------------
defect_id
estimate_date
ready_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You are treating a database like a spread sheet. It would be better to set up a table on these lines:

```
DefectID
TestDate
Est_ReadyForRetest
```

This means that you are adding records each day, rather than fields. It will also make queries easier.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion that the data ought to be normalized, but then you have a different problem for answering the question, one that I'm not sure how you'd do it in SQL (since it is based on the order of the records). That is, you'd have to walk a recordset to do it. I guess a correlated subquery could do the trick, but it would have to based on something that can be ordered.

My SQL skills are not fabulous, so in the abstract I won't suggest a SQL solution, but maybe somebody else will.

Instead, I'll suggest a function that could return the answer in the original unnormalized data structure. I base this on my existing iMax() function, which goes like this:

```
  Public Function iMax(ParamArray p()) As Variant
  ' Idea from Trevor Best in Usenet MessageID 
  '   rib5dv45ko62adf2v0d1cot4kiu5t8mbdp@4ax.com
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngUBound As Long
    Dim v As Variant

    v = p(LBound(p))
    lngUBound = UBound(p)
    For i = LBound(p) + 1 To lngUBound
      If v < p(i) Then
         v = p(i)
      End If
    Next
    iMax = v
  End Function
```

The idea is using a parameter array to pass the values to the function, and then walking the array to get the information you need. In this case, you'd want to walk the array and count the number of times it changes, something like this:

```
  Public Function CountChange(ParamArray varInput()) As Long
    Dim varValue As Variant
    Dim varPrevious As Variant
    Dim lngCount As Long

    varPrevious = varInput(0)
    For Each varValue In varInput()
      If varValue <> varPrevious Then
         lngCount = lngCount + 1
      End If
      varPrevious = varValue
    Next varValue
    CountChange = lngCount
  End Function
```

I haven't tested that very thoroughly, and it doesn't deal with Nulls at all, but that's the idea -- it's very useful concept for comparing data from fields within a single row.